# iPhone App CrashReport

Tags: iphone

How to get the CrashReport from iPhone?

Thanks
Vadivelu

Answer (score 2):

Open Xcode. Go to the organizer window. Select one of your attached devices. Look for a tab named 'Device logs' on the right.

Once you have released your app to the public, you will get crash logs from users through iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2):

Application crash logs are transfered to your computer each time you do a sync with the device, in the iTunes. Thus, first step is to sync with iTunes:

Mac OS X –

On the Mac, crash logs are kept at:

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
```

where ~ is your Home folder.

Windows Vista –

Files are located here:

```
C:/Users/<USERNAME>/AppData/Roaming/Apple computer/LogsCrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>
```

AppData folder is hidden by default, , so you need to reveal it by typing the address in My Computer’s address bar.

Windows XP –

Location is here:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/<USERNAME>/Application Data/Apple computer/LogsCrashReporter/<DEVICE_NAME>
```

is your login username. Application Data folder is usually hidden by default, so you need to reveal it in the same way as in Vista — by typing in and pressing Enter.

check out my blog entry here - http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-and-windows/

Comment: You should always reply here, not link to other websites.

Comment: answer edited I hope you can remove this negative vote now @Javier Soto

Comment: @Saurabh I appreciate both the content and the link to your blog post. Great work!

Answer (score 0):

see [Technical Note TN2151](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184)

> When an application crashes on the
>   iPhone or iPod touch, a "crash report"
>   is stored on the device. Crash reports
>   describe the conditions under which
>   the application terminated, in most
>   cases including a complete stack trace
>   for each executing thread, and are
>   typically very useful for debugging
>   issues in the application.
>
> When the user synchronizes their
>   device using iTunes, crash reports are
>   copied to a directory on the user's
>   computer. If the application was
>   distributed via the App Store and the
>   user has chosen to submit crash logs
>   to Apple, the crash log will be
>   uploaded and the developer can
>   download it via iTunes Connect. For
>   applications that have been
>   distributed using Ad Hoc or Enterprise
>   methods, getting crash reports
>   requires user cooperation.
>   Specifically, the user will need to
>   retrieve the crash report from the
>   directory where it was copied by
>   iTunes. Depending on the platform, the
>   directory is:
>
> Mac OS X:
>   ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/
>
> Windows XP: C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application
>   Data\Apple
>   Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\
>
> Windows Vista or 7:
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Apple
>   Computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\
>
> is the user's login name
>   for the computer.  is the
>   name of the iPod touch or iPhone, for
>   example, "John's iPhone".
>
> You are only interested in .crash
>   files. The crash report's file name
>   begins with the application name and
>   contains date/time information. In
>   addition,  will appear at
>   the end of the file name, before the
>   extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Test Flight sdk to get to know the crash report , and also other info related to crash like how did get crashed. Here is the link where you will know how to use::

http://changhoward.blogspot.in/2012/02/ios-developer-how-to-use-testflight-to.html